# Why is database connection in Google Cloud Build slow?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-sql, codeception, google-cloud-build

I'm running a YII project that uses Codeception for unit and integration testing. In my Dockerfile, the last step of my build is to run the integration test with `RUN ./vendor/bin/codecept run`

I have already set up CloudSQL and whitelisted the IP address so that CloudBuild can establish a connection to the DB.

In the cloudbuild.yaml, I have the first step to build the docker image:

```
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
      - '--build-arg'
      - environmentId=$_GCPENVIRONMENTID
    id: Build
```

When the docker runs the integration test `RUN ./vendor/bin/codecept run` on CloudBuild, it is incredibly slow when it involves database connection. When I benchmark this against my local machine, while connecting to the same CloudSQL DB, it runs at least 10 times faster.

I've done everything I can to isolate the issue. CloudSQL runs fast. The Docker build is fast. But for some reason, Database connection from CloudBuild to CloudSQL is really slow. Why is that?

## CloudSQL configuration

- Database: MySQL 8.0.18
- Cores: 1vCPU
- RAM: 614.4 MB
- Storage: SSD

## Test Results

I ran 2 test run with 2 different database. In each test run, I run with Cloud Build and my own localhost. As control, I have test script that includes testing without database interaction.

The results are near identical, as expected from network connection. Both database are hosting in Singapore region.

### Test 1 - Google Cloud SQL

- Cloud Build - 10 seconds to 1.5 minutes
- Localhost - 1 second to 4 seconds
- Cloud Build Controls - < 10ms
- Localhost Controls - < 50ms

### Test 2 - Digital Ocean database

- Cloud Build - 10 seconds to 1.5 minutes
- Localhost - 1 second to 4 seconds
- Cloud Build Controls - < 10ms
- Localhost Controls - < 50ms

Comment: To look into this, can you please provide the source of information you are using to create the YII project? This would be valuable.

Comment: I have 2 main sources, first is the build log in Google Cloud Build, which states the duration of each test I run. The second is the console output from my own localhost, which states the exact same test. In both test, I run the exact same database and same codes.

When I look at the duration of each test, I noticed that when the test involves database interaction, it is at least 10 times slower. Those without database interaction, Cloud Build is as fast, if not faster. 

I added more details to my original question.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. I meant where did you get the information to create a YII project that uses Codeception.

Comment: Oh... This is a private repo which already has codeception configured before I took over this project. It basically has "codeception/base": "^2.2.3", "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1" in the composer.json file. The rest of the test suite is located in the respective /test/ folder. Every test run is working as expected, on local dev machine and on CloudBuild. The difference is in the duration of the test, which is unusually long in CloudBuild.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your scenario. It seems like this may be an issue with your project or configuration. I would encourage you to use the link https://cloud.google.com/support to get the support you need.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. I also suspect that it could be due to outdated libraries in the composer.lock files. When I updated the libraries on my local dev, the project ran slightly faster. I can't push the new libraries to cloudbuild yet, but I'll try out this when I can. I will also look into getting Google Support from your link.

Comment: I've also noticed that Cloud SQL interaction from Cloud Build is pretty slow - I don't see much CPU usage on Cloud SQL instance, yet it takes ~32x longer to run `rspec` unit tests as a build step than it does to run locally.  I've tried building with a 32-core Instance Type with same results. Cloud SQL is in same zone as Cloud Build to reduce latency too, yet still very slow to run unit tests.

Comment: What is the database and version you are connecting to?  Windows or Linux? RAM, Cores, SSD or NVME data storage?

Comment: Database: MySQL 8.0.0 |
Windows or Linux? Not sure. |
RAM: 614.4 MB |
Storage: SSD |
Cores: 1vCPU

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @ProFire You may have to ask Google Cloud to provide htop/top, ulimit, iostat data from OS Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I think Cloud Build is network-limited (at least to Cloud SQL) to ~16kbps ingress and ~2kbps egress.  I get these numbers by noting that no matter what instance class I use for my Cloud SQL MySQL instances, when I run unit testing, I see different CPU and Memory usage, yet same network traffic amount.   I've also tried this using different Cloud Build `machine-type` values and even large-CPU/large-Memory types result in the same test-time (slow).

Answer (score 1):

I had word with Google Support. It seems that all Cloud Build triggers is running on us-central1. Connection to regions outside of us-central1 has a network performance penalty. As for my case, since my database is located in Singapore region, I experience severe performance penalty.

There is currently a way to port all Cloud Build to other selected regions. Unfortunately, this feature is still in beta and Singapore is not among the selected regions that can run Cloud Build.

If you're lucky enough to be in a region that support Cloud Build in beta, you may sign up to be in the wait-list at https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdAkLtvPUQFCgAUcHUi1VDHn_GaQz_sDOvFxpg3JXIJdIZY6g/viewform

This answer isn't exactly a solution, but I hope it can provide some insights to the cause of the problem.